# angular router-outlet load before header component, how to prevent?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, router-outlet

As in the `app-component.html` below. The `router-outlet` components load before `app-header` component. How to prevent router components to load before header and footer.

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<app-header *ngIf="router.url !== '/login' && router.url !== '/register-user'"> 
</app-header>

<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer *ngIf="router.url !== '/login' && 
router.url !== '/register-user'"></app-footer>
```

Comment: I am guessing that `*ngIf`is checking for an async task and your landing component is not and that's why is taking some time to load. Try adding a check of `*ngIf="router.url"` in the container div.

Comment: no this is not the cause.